# Copy constructor of dynamic two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor

I need help. Now i'm trying to make a class Matrix, but my program freezes every time I run it in Visual Studio 2013. I think there is some trouble with copy constructor. Here is the whole code. `

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    int** matrix;
    int X; // Matrix rows
    int Y; // Matrix columns
public:
    // Default Constructor
    Matrix()
    {
        X = 0;
        Y = 0;
        matrix = NULL;
    }
    // Constructor with parameters
    Matrix(int _X, int _Y)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));

        X = _X;
        Y = _Y;
        matrix = new int*[X];

        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
                matrix[i] = new int[Y];

        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            }
        }

    }
    // Copy constructor
    Matrix(const Matrix& N)
    {
        X = N.X;
        Y = N.Y;

        matrix = new int*[X];

        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
            matrix[i] = new int[Y];

        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = N.matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    // Destructor
    ~Matrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
            delete[] matrix[X];
    }
    //--------------------------------------
    void ShowMatrixOnScreen()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
                cout << matrix[i][j] << "   ";

            cout << endl << endl;
        }
    }
};

void main() 
{
    Matrix x(4, 2);
    x.ShowMatrixOnScreen();
}
```

`

Function "ShowMatrixOnScreen" prints matrix "x" on a screen, but then console freezes.

Comment: As an aside, you forgot to `delete[] matrix;`.

Comment: ...And `void main()` should be `int main()`

Comment: ...And copy constructor is never executed with the main you wrote.

Comment: @BrainOverflow I advice to see my answer because you have more mistakes than you think.:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your destructor has the statement 
`delete[] matrix[X];`

`matrix[X]` does not exist, so you are freeing memory which is not allocated to you, which is Undefined Behavior. It should be `delete [] matrix[i]` instead!

Moreover, as pointed by Vlad From Moscow, it is advisable to `delete` all the memory, so you shall also consider adding `delete [] matrix`, to delete the 1-D array of pointers which you allocated using `matrix = new int*[X];`

Comment: @BrainOverflow I  have been through this, it happens!

Comment: For that matters I think `delete[] matrix[X];` causes UB, which doesn't necessarily results in a runtime error.

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your destructor is invalid

First of all in this loop

```
    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
        delete[] matrix[X];
```

it tries to access non-existent element `matrix[X]`  beyond the allocated array. The valid range for indices is `[0, X - 1]`

So you have to write

```
    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
        delete[] matrix[i];
                       ^^^
```

But thsi loop is valid only if `matrix` is not equal to `nullptr` Therefore before the loop you have to check whether `matrix` is equal to `nullptr` or not equal.

And also you need to delete the memory allocated to the first one-dimensionl array

```
delete [] matrix;
```

Thus the destructor will look like

```
~Matrix()
{
    if ( matrix )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < X; i++ ) delete []matrix[i];
    }

    delete []matrix;
}
```

Also in the copy constructor you should also check whether data member `matrix` of the copied object also is not equal to `nullptr`

```
// Copy constructor
Matrix(const Matrix& N)
{
    X = N.X;
    Y = N.Y;

    if ( N.matrix )
    {
        matrix = new int*[X];

        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
            matrix[i] = new int[Y];

        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = N.matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It would be much better if data members `X` and `Y` has type `size_t`. Otherwise you need also to check whether they are not negative.

The allocation of the memory could be placed in a separate private member function.

for example

```
int ** allocate( size_t m, size_t n )
{
    int **p = nullptr;

    if ( n != 0 && m != 0 )
    {
        matrix = new int *[m];

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ ) matrix[i] = new int[n];
    }

    return p;
}
```

In the class definition data members `X` and `Y` should precede data member matrix

```
private:
    int X; // Matrix rows
    int Y; // Matrix columns    
    int** matrix;
```

In this case you could use mem-initializer list of constructors to initialize the class data members.

For example

```
// Constructor with parameters
Matrix(int X, int Y) : X( X ), Y( Y ), matrix( allocate( X, Y ) )
{
   if ( matrix )
   {
       srand(time(NULL));

        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the default constructor could be defined like

```
// Default Constructor
Matrix() : Matrix( 0, 0 )
{
}
```

In turn the copy constructor could be defined like

```
// Copy constructor
Matrix( const Matrix &N ) : X( N.X ), Y( N.Y ), matrix( allocate( N.X, N.Y ) )
{
    if ( matrix )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = N.matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you should define also the copy assignment operator or define it as deleted.
Otherwise there will be problems when you try to assign one object of the class to another.

Take into account that function main shall have return type `int`

`int` main()

Comment: Thanks a lot for comprehensive answer. Some of things you are talking about a new to me. For example "mem-initializer list". But this should be another question. Thank you one more time!